# How do I make button image sizes dynamic to fit grid layout container in XML? (Android)

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic, size

I have a `gridView` with a number of image and text `widgets`. The XML looks like this (the rest of the widgets look the same):

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="218dp"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/graphicContainer">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/cookieImageButton"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="#0000"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/cookie_icon_60at3x"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="300dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:autoSizeMinTextSize="40px"
        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        android:fontFamily="@font/youre_so_cool_regular"
        android:text="Cookies"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="369dp" />
```

Giving a result looking like [image: this]

This is fine, but I want the `widgets` (the image buttons and text views) size to change dynamically to fill the entire `gridView`. Is there a way to do this in XML? I have looked for an answer, and found alternatives like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444042/java-resize-image-dynamically-to-fit-grids-in-gridlayout`

But it seems unnecessary complex and something that could and should be fixed using some XML code. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Try to give imagebutton width and height as wrap_content

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but no, the images are so big that everything disappears from view.

Comment: then you give size.

Comment: @Android Team Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code ..
add below dependency into app level gradle file.

```
  implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
```

then after change this things..

```
<GridLayout android:id="@+id/grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
android:columnCount="3"
android:rowCount="4"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/graphicContainer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/cookieImageButton"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:background="#0000"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cookie_icon_60at3x"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="33dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="300dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="40px"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:fontFamily="@font/youre_so_cool_regular"
    android:text="Cookies"
    android:textAlignment="center"  
      tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="@dimen/_33sdp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="@dimen/_369sdp" />
```

Comment: Hey, that certainly took things in the right direction. Thanks a lot @Android Team !!! :D